# What is the different way to do heading underline stylish?

Tags: html, css

I want to do the same things as below but in a different way using CSS.

[image: Slanted underline using CSS]

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px;
  display: block;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin: 0;
  width: 500px;
}

.heading-border {
  position: relative;
  background: url('https://i.ibb.co/PM2s0mj/green-shape.png');
  background-size: 100% 8px;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.heading-border:before {
  content: ' ';
  background: #fff;
  height: 13px;
  width: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 0px -8px -6px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.heading-border:after {
  content: ' ';
  background: #fff;
  height: 13px;
  width: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px -6px -17px 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>This is heading <span class='heading-border'>this is stylish heading line</span></h2>
</div>
```

This has happened when I used a background color
http://prntscr.com/ny8uog

I want the same things as I mentioned in the above code but in a different way so if I will use background color in behind of heading then the patch should not be visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a background like below and you can easily control the angle, color and dimension of the line:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px;
  display: block;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin: 0;
  width: 500px;
}

.heading-border {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(-225deg,transparent 5px, pink 0) bottom left, /*225 = 180 + 45 */
    linear-gradient(-45deg ,transparent 5px, pink 0) bottom right;
  background-size: 51% 7px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


body {
 background:linear-gradient(to right,yellow,blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>This is heading <span class='heading-border'>this is stylish heading line</span></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the color of the `:before` and `:after` psudo-elements of your `heading-border` to match that of your background color like so:

```
.heading-border:before {
  content: ' ';
  background: #a09898; /* <--- change to bg color */
  ...
}

.heading-border:after {
  content: ' ';
  background: #a09898; /* <--- change to bg color */
  ...
}
```

See example below:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #a09898;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin: 0;
  width: 500px;
}

.heading-border {
  position: relative;
  background: url('https://i.ibb.co/PM2s0mj/green-shape.png');
  background-size: 100% 8px;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.heading-border:before {
  content: ' ';
  background: #a09898;
  height: 13px;
  width: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 0px -8px -6px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.heading-border:after {
  content: ' ';
  background: #a09898;
  height: 13px;
  width: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px -6px -17px 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>This is heading <span class='heading-border'>this is stylish heading line</span></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: It will not work because background should be in different color and i want to do it for all the cases.

Answer (score 0):

I Think this will work for you!!!

```css
.stylish-underline{
    border-bottom: solid 8px #fbd2d7!important;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: solid 8px transparent;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px;
  display: block;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin: 0;
  width: 500px;
      display: contents;
}
.right-arrow{
width: 0px;
    background: #fbd2d7;
    height: 0px;
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
    border: solid 8px transparent;
    border-right: solid 8px #fff;
    border-bottom: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
   .right-arrow{
    width: 0px;
    background: #fbd2d7;
    height: 0px;
    display: -webkit-inline-box;
    border: solid 8px transparent;
    border-right: solid 8px #fff;
    border-bottom: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 41px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h2>This is heading  <span class="stylish-underline"> this is stylish <br> heading line</span></h2>
<div class="right-arrow">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The tip on the right end of the underline should be at the top, not the bottom, according to OP.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.... Really appreciate...
But my pattern is quite different.
This is curve is quite different please see below snap.
http://prntscr.com/ny9enn

Comment: It would be great if you could try some different logic.

Comment: .stylish-underline{
    border-bottom: solid 8px #fbd2d7!important;
    border-radius: 8px;
}  use this class instead of this.

Comment: We can't add border-radius it will mess up with things. you can try it your own code so you can get an idea. Also, the left side curve is fine but we need to correct right side curve as I mention in my snap.